# Add data to end of ko.observablearray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I'm trying to add data to the end of an observable array but it's just not working as expected. I bet it is something minor but I just can't get my head around it.

What I am doing:

```
      self.businesses = ko.observableArray();

        function Business(business) {
            var self = this;
            self.BusinessID = ko.observable(business.BusinessID );
            self.Type = ko.observable(business.Type);
            self.Location = ko.observable(business.Location);
        }

    /*ajax get array of businesses as follows:
 [
        {
            "$id": "1",
            "BusinessID ": 62,
            "Type": "Data",
            "Location": "Data"
            },
        {
            "$id": "2",
            "BusinessID ": 63,
            "Type": "Data",
            "Location": "Data"
        },
        {
            "$id": "3",
            "BusinessID ": 64,
            "Type": "Data",
            "Location": "Data",      
        } ]
    */

                var mappedBusinesses = $.map(data, function (business) { return new Business(business) });
            self.businesses(mappedBusinesses);
```

This all works as expected and the obersablearray is populated.

However if I go to add another business, it wont work. For example, if I call the ajax that returns this (as newBusiness):

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "BusinessID ": 68,
    "Type": "Data",
    "Location": "Data"
}
```

and I do:

```
self.businesses().push(newBusiness);
```

It adds to the array as an "Object" not a Business. So I thought I would do:

```
var bus = $.map(newBusiness, function (business) { return new Business(business) });
self.businesses().push(bus);
```

But I get the error in the JS console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'BusinessID' of null

So I made a new var and added the brackets: [] in and it adds to the observable array but not as a "Business" object but rather as an "Array[1]" object at the end and this doesn't function as per the others. Code as follows:

```
    var newBus = {
            BusinessID: newBusiness.BusinessID,
            Type: newBusiness.Type,
            Location: newBusiness.Location               
}

        var bus = $.map(newBus, function (business) { return new Business(business) });
    self.businesses().push(bus);
```

As mentioned this adds to the observable array but doesn't actually add as a "business" object but rather as an "array[1]" object.

I bet it's something so basic but just can't get it working!

Comment: I can see an extra white space after BusinessID property in JSON. I am not sure if this could cause an issue. Is this white space intended?

Comment: `dperry` mentioned one should work trying without `()` and push . else let us know . cheers

Comment: Sorry - the whitespace is just copy / editing / pasting by me (didn't wanna show the whole request as it's too large). I tried without the () but I get an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return Type }"
Message: Type is not defined. Looks like it's coming from the HTML page as I have a table with a "foreach: businesses" and a tr element with: "text: Type".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argh I knew it would be simple!

It was posting the whole array to the ObservableArray...not just the object.

The fix:

```
self.businesses.push(newBusiness[0])
```

Had to add the [0] in to get it to push the actual data into the array, not the object!

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

You're evaluating the array with your push:

```
self.businesses().push(newBusiness);
```

Observable Arrays have their own array functions, you should just do this (no parens):

```
self.businesses.push(newBusiness);
```

See this page: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html